# Cannot find type definition file for 'cypress'.ts

Tags: xpath, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

When trying to npm install -D cypress-xpath into a Cypress project [require('cypress-xpath') added to my cypress/support/index.js] with the cypress-cucumber-preprocessor already installed I am getting the below Error in the plugins > index.js file for `"/// <reference types="cypress" />"`?

Cannot find type definition file for 'cypress'.ts(2688)

Added to plugins > index.js file

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
module.exports = (on, config) => {
on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

package.json file

```
"devdependencies": {
    "cypress": "^8.3.1",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "Dependencies": {
    "cypress-xpath": "^1.6.2"
  }
```

support > index.js file

```
require('cypress-xpath')
```

When running:

```
npx cypress open
```

The plugins file is missing or invalid.

Your pluginsFile is set to C:\Users\Delwin\VSCode\Cypress\Cucumber1\cypress\plugins\index.js, but either the file is missing, it contains a syntax error, or threw an error when required. The pluginsFile must be a .js, .ts, or .coffee file.

Or you might have renamed the extension of your pluginsFile. If that's the case, restart the test runner.

Please fix this, or set pluginsFile to false if a plugins file is not necessary for your project.

Error: Cannot find module 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor'

Comment: I met the same error described in your title(TS2688), and I solve it by upgrade my cypress version. Here's the [detail](https://ezdocs.notion.site/Cypress-10-1-0-ts-TS2688-c4a7b6a432664c1e835c9ca6dc39106f).

Answer (score 12):

My problem was solved by installing latest cypress types

`npm i -D @types/cypress@latest`

Comment: Previously, when I ran `npm I -D @types/cypress`. it did nothing. but after running `npm I -D @types/cypress@latest` It worked for me 

Answer (score 1):

I added the following tsconfig.json file an ran `npm i -D @types/cypress@latest` worked for me.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
      "types": ["cypress", "node"]
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error and I fixed by installing cypress,
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress

Answer (score 0):

Add <reference types="@cypress/xpath into the command.js file[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, but installing cypress in the project root path and creating "jsconfig.json" in the project root folder, solved the problem.

jsconfig.json ->

```
{
    "include": ["./node_modules/cypress", "cypress/**/*.js"]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem got sloved by writing

reference types="@cypress/xpath"

instead of

reference types="cypress-xpath"